# simplexml_load_string() doesn't like foreign languages

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, simplexml

I am receiving an XML response which comes through perfectly.

Words such as "português" and "españa" are correctly formatted.

However, once I have parsed the XML through the php function `simplexml_load_string()`, the words are transformed as follows: "portugu�s" and "espa�a".

Comment: Does the XML include a declaration which declares the encoding, e.g. `<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>`?

Comment: Yes - the XML response is a yahoo boss search result response.

Comment: Please stop editing my question. I just had to edit it because the question had been turned from "are in order" to "are in correctly formatted" which is the opposite. Stop now - enough!

Comment: @Haraldo: I'm pretty sure that edit was done in good faith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple XML always treats text internally as UTF-8 encoded, converting to and from this character set if necessary. To solve your issue either make sure that all output from your app is UTF-8 encoded or convert it to another character set (possibly using utf8decode()).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. UTF-8 is the encoding I'm using so I don't understand why these characters are changing. The main trouble came about when these characters stopped me from inserting the data into the database. The insert just plain fails. Remove these words and the insert works.

Comment: I was using strtolower on a the words. This function can corrupt UTF8 characters.

Read this for more useful info:

http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8