# What is happening when SimpleXML parses XML with special characters?

Tags: php, simplexml, special-characters

I am trying to solve this problem I am having with my final output.

The XML feed looks like this...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<item> <title>TRON: Legacy, 2010 - ★★★</title>
```

I would like to preserve the stars in the final output but my final output looks like this...

**TRON: Legacy, 2010 - â˜…â˜…â˜…**

Here is the code I am using in PHP -

```
$title = $item->title; 
$movieLink = $item->link;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo "<div class=\"movies\">";
echo "<a href=\"$movieLink\">$title</a>";
```

I know this might be an encoding issue of some kind and I've tried converting the string using htmlentities but with no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [simplexml_load_string() doesn't like foreign languages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5943555/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$title` will be an UTF-8 encoded string in the output. Signal the browser that your website is in UTF-8 and everything is fine:

```
header("Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

See as well: [Setting the HTTP charset parameter](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php)

Only Questionmarks what that means? Probably the [quick answer](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#answer) is helpful.